# How do I customize all the names of the child threads of a ThreadFactory in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

If I am extending an existing ThreadFactory implementation, how would I go able ensuring that all threads created would have the same prefix? I'm sick and tired of looking at `Thread-9` in my logs and would like to distinguish between threads more easily.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to go about this?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/6113746/466738

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provide your own implementation of the ThreadFactory interface:

```
pool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(numberOfThreads, new TF());

class TF implements ThreadFactory {
    public synchronized Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread t = new Thread(r) ;
        t.setName("Something here....");  
        return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. However, the API I am using only allows me to specify the ThreadPool class implementation and not the ThreadFactory implementation.

Comment: What do you mean by ThreadPool class ? Which interface do you have to work with ? Executor ?

Comment: Wow. I feel stupid. ThreadPool is an interface in Quartz. Thank you for your answer. I think it will be useful. I'm going to update the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should use your own custom thread factory. The default factories are not much of use. Implement a ThreadFactoryBuilder to create you custom thread factories that allows you to do the following:

1. Have custom thread names
2. Have choice of threads - User or Daemon threads
3. Have choice of Thread Priority
4. Have flexibility to set uncaught exception handlers

You have a sample ThreadFactoryBuilder implementation in the following post which you can use.

http://wilddiary.com/understanding-java-threadfactory-creating-custom-thread-factories/

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide your own [ThreadFactory](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) ? That will allow you to create threads with whatever naming convention you require.