# How to change the name of threads in an ExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I'm using an ExecutorService to execute some Callables, but the name of the threads are like fixed-pool-1-thread-1.

How I change the name of the threads? If it's not possible, there another way to execute Callables that I can set the name of threadS?

Comment: I just asked this the other day - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113746/naming-threads-and-thread-pools-of-executorservice

Comment: @mre, Yeah, it gets asked a lot.

Comment: TL;DR Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9748697/231917

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll have to use an `ExecutorService` implementation that allows you to set the `ThreadFactory`[1](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) used to create threads, for example, [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html). Pass an instance that creates threads with the proper names.

There's also a handy class in commons-lang that allows to specify thread names with a pattern: [`BasicThreadFactory`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/concurrent/BasicThreadFactory.html). This keeps you from having to create a `ThreadFactory` subclass just to provide the naming behavior.

Comment: +1, for Javadoc reference and correct/concise answer

Comment: There is some native java implementation of the ThreadFactory interface?

Comment: @Renato, the only accessible library implementation is from the `Executors` utility class and it does not allow you to supply a name string.

Answer (score 7):

Guava almost always has what you [need](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ThreadFactoryBuilder.html#setNameFormat%28java.lang.String%29). `ThreadFactory namedThreadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("my-sad-thread-%d").build()` and pass it off to your `ExecutorService`.

Comment: @pathrikrit, the above link no longer works.

Answer (score 4):

A quick and dirty way;

```
public void run() {
    Thread.currentThread().setName(aName);
    doStuff();
}
```

Comment: This assumes that you can change the run method of the Thread.