# How to use Thread Pool concept in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am creating a http proxy server in java. I have a class named **Handler** which is responsible for processing the requests and responses coming and going from web browser and to web server respectively. I have also another class named **Copy** which copies the inputStream object to outputStream object . Both these classes implement **Runnable** interface. I would like to use the concept of Thread pooling in my design, however i don't know how to go about that! Any hint or idea would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

I suggest you look at Executor and ExecutorService.  They add a lot of good stuff to make it easier to use Thread pools.

...

@Azad provided some good information and links.  You should also buy and read the book *Java Concurrency in Practice*.  (often abbreviated as JCiP)  Note to stackoverflow big-wigs - how about some revenue link to Amazon???

Below is my brief summary of how to use and take advantage of ExecutorService with thread pools.  Let's say you want 8 threads in the pool.

You can create one using the full featured constructors of ThreadPoolExecutor, e.g.

```
ExecutorService service = new ThreadPoolExecutor(8,8, more args here...);
```

or you can use the simpler but less customizable Executors factories, e.g.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
```

One advantage you immediately get is the ability to `shutdown()` or `shutdownNow()` the thread pool, and to check this status via `isShutdown()` or `isTerminated()`.

If you don't care much about the Runnable you wish to run, or they are very well written, self-contained, never fail or log any errors appropriately, etc... you can call

```
execute(Runnable r);
```

If you do care about either the result (say, it calculates pi or downloads an image from a webpage) and/or you care if there was an Exception, you should use one of the submit methods that returns a Future.  That allows you, at some time in the future, check if the task `isDone()` and to retrieve the result via `get()`.  If there was an Exception, `get()` will throw it (wrapped in an ExecutionException).  Note - even of your Future doesn't "return" anything (it is of type Void) it may still be good practice to call `get()` (ignoring the void result) to test for an Exception.

However, this checking the Future is a bit of chicken and egg problem.  The whole point of a thread pool is to submit tasks without blocking.  But Future.get() blocks, and Future.isDone() begs the questions of which thread is calling it, and what it does if it isn't done - do you sleep() and block?

If you are submitting a known *chunk of related of tasks* simultaneously, e.g., you are performing some big mathematical calculation like a matrix multiply that can be done in parallel, and there is no particular advantage to obtaining partial results, you can call `invokeAll()`.  The calling thread will then block until all the tasks are complete, when you can call `Future.get()` on all the Futures.

What if the tasks are more disjointed, or you really want to use the partial results?  Use ExecutorCompletionService, which wraps an ExecutorService.  As tasks get completed, they are added to a queue.  This makes it easy for a single thread to poll and remove events from the queue.  JCiP has a great example of an web page app that downloads all the images in parallel, and renders them as soon as they become available for responsiveness.

Comment: Can you give me some examples on how to use Executor and ExecutorService with the classes that implements runnable interface? I have no idea how to use Executor and ExectorService to create a thread pooling environment! Thanx

Comment: Unfortunately I'm travelling this weekend so wont be able to help much till Monday.

Comment: No worries! I will check on you again! I appreciate

Comment: @Xris - I'm back from travelling, just added a bunch of stuff.  Check it out.  And definitely go buy `Java Concurrency in Practice` to see their example of a web-page renderer.

Comment: Goooood summary.Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

I hope below will help you:,
**class Executor**
An `object` that executes submitted `Runnable` tasks. This interface provides a way of *decoupling task submission from the mechanics of how each task will be run, including details of thread use, scheduling, etc.* An Executor is normally used instead of explicitly creating `threads`. For example, rather than invoking `new Thread(new(RunnableTask())).start()` for each of a set of tasks, you might use:

```
Executor executor = anExecutor;
 executor.execute(new RunnableTask1());
 executor.execute(new RunnableTask2());
 ...
```

**class ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor**
A `ThreadPoolExecutor` that can additionally *schedule commands to run after a given delay, or to execute periodically*. This class is preferable to Timer when multiple worker threads are needed, or when the additional flexibility or capabilities of `ThreadPoolExecutor` (which this class extends) are required.

Delayed tasks execute no sooner than they are enabled, but without any real-time guarantees about when, after they are enabled, they will commence. Tasks scheduled for exactly the same execution time are enabled in `first-in-first-out (FIFO)` order of submission.

and 
**Interface ExecutorService**
An `Executor` that provides methods to *manage termination and methods that can produce a Future for tracking progress of one or more asynchronous tasks*.

An `ExecutorService` can be shut down, which will cause it to stop accepting new tasks. After being shut down, the executor will eventually terminate, at which point no tasks are actively executing, no tasks are awaiting execution, and no new tasks can be submitted. 


 **Edited:** 
you can find example to use `Executor` and `ExecutorService` 
[here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-concurrency-%E2%80%93-part-7)
[here](http://jovialjava.blogspot.com/2011/01/part-7-javautilconcurrent-invokeall-via.html)
and [here](http://www.softwareengineeringsolutions.com/blogs/2010/07/21/implementing-thread-pools-using-java-executors/)
 [Question will be useful for you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113746/naming-threads-and-thread-pools-of-executorservice)