# ExecutorService naming conventions Java

Tags: java, multithreading, naming-conventions

I have recently found myself using some ExecutorServices (SingleThreadScheduledExecutor and newFixedThreadPool) but I don't have any kind of good name for them.

Are there any kind of guidelines or conventions about naming these kinds of objects? I have seen names like "workerThread" used for SingleThreadScheduledExecutors, is this correct as they are not exactly threads?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although this is primarily opinion based, I'm using the following conventions in my code:

- A Field or parameter that references an `Executor` or an `ExecutorService` is named `executor` or `executorService`. The type of the executor should not be inferable by the name of the field as otherwise you cannot easily change the executor implementation afterwards.
- A class that implements `Runnable` or `Callable` to realize a long-running operation usually gets the suffix `Task` (like `LoadTask`, `ComputationTask`, ...). (As such an operation **is not** a thread, but **is executed by** a thread, and there is usually not a 1:1 mapping between threads and operations, it is wrong to call it *thread*).

This makes the code really readable and it does not make any assumption about thread usage, e.g.:

```
for (String fileName : fileNames) {
    executor.execute(new LoadTask(fileName));
}
```

(This example might execute all load tasks in serial, in parallel or anything inbetween - according to the type of executor that's used).

*One note about the word 'thread':*

The word *thread* is not used anywhere except for the rare case where I have to either subclass from `Thread` or create a field that references a (real) `Thread`:

```
public class WorkerThread extends Thread { ... }
```

or:

```
Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
```

Answer (score 0):

[This question is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113746/naming-threads-and-thread-pools-of-executorservice), it might be able to help you.

You can always build a string using a generic object name + PID + something else and hash the result. Chances of a hash collision are pretty low...

Comment: I think the question is about naming conventions for fields and classes, not about how to name the threads.

Comment: hm. One possibility would be threadName_variableName or threadHash_variableName for a convention