# Program hangs as threads don't terminate

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm having this odd behaviour. My program hangs eventhough I'm setting a time to force terminate it. could anyone point out what this strange behaviour could be?

here is my code where I start the threads

```
protected void pendingTaskStarter() throws Exception {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxThreadNum);
    ArrayList<Future<Runnable>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<Runnable>>();

    System.out.println("max thread num: " + maxThreadNum);
    for(int i=0;i<maxThreadNum;i++){

        Thread t = new PendingTaskConsumer();
        Future<?> f=service.submit(t);
        futures.add((Future<Runnable>) f);  
    }

    for (Future<?> future:futures) {
        future.get(5l,TimeUnit.MINUTES); // maximum thread's life is 5min (5l <-- 5 in long )
    }   
    service.shutdownNow();

}
```

I am 100% sure that my program hangs somewhere in `PendingTaskConsumer` class based on the outputs within `PendingTaskConsumer` class.

Anyways codes in PendingTaskConsumer should be irrelevant as thread is supposedly forced to be terminated.
My question is in what scenraios the following line does not do as its expected.

```
future.get(5l,TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

The program is running on `Linux(Ubuntu)` and using `openjdk-7-jdk backage ( version 1.7)`

Comment: How long is the program expected to run for? How long have you waited for it to complete?

Comment: I have an API on top of this layer, where if this program doesn't terminate within 20min, then it reboots the machine that this program is running

Comment: (1) Why is `PendingTaskConsumer` derived from `Thread`? It is not a thread, but a task that is executed by ANOTHER thread maintained by the `ExecutorService`. (2) is `PendingTaskConsumer()` a method call? If no, it is probalby missing the `new` keyword.

Comment: @isnot2bad PendingTaskConsumer is class, in the question I missed putting keyword "new" before,

Comment: @nafas OK. But still you should not derive from `Thread` here! `PendingConsumer` is just a `Runnable` or `Callable`, not a thread by its own! (The threads are managed by the executor _internally_!)

Comment: @isnot2bad that's interesting mate, PendingConsumer is basically a class that extends Thread, why would you think I shouldn't do this?  (ps this is a question, I'm not trying to say you are wrong or anything)

Comment: @nafas No, it's the other way round: Why _should_ you do this? Your `ExecutorService` wants to have a `Runnable` (or `Callable`), so this is exactly what you should implement. Your code just uses the fact that `Thread` already implements `Runnable`, but it does never start the thread. Just replace `PendingTaskConsumer extends Thread` by `PendingTaskConsumer implements Runnable` and all will be fine (except that it will not solve your actual problem).

Comment: @nafas see also my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990818/executorservice-naming-conventions-java. It also discusses the difference between a thread and a task.

Comment: @isnot2bad hehe mate, I like the part of comment "(except that it will not solve your actual problem)" . I have changed all my threads to Runnable. I suppose it a good practice that I should start getting used to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @GPI already stated in his/her answer, cancellation won't work properly, if your tasks do not repond to thread interruption via `Thread.interrupt()`. See [Oracle: The Java™ Tutorials - Concurrency - Interrupts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) or [Java Executors: how can I stop submitted tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418033/java-executors-how-can-i-stop-submitted-tasks).

But even if your tasks do not immediately stop if the thread is interrupted (=the interruption flag is set), you can timeout your method. Just don't listen to task completion by invoking every single `get()` method of your `Future`s! That's not necessary as you are not really interested in their result. Just shutdown your `ExecutorService` and wait for its termination.

```
protected void pendingTaskStarter() throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxThreadNum);

    for (int i = 0; i < maxThreadNum; i++) {
        service.submit(new PendingTaskConsumer());
    }

    // Shutdown service.
    // This will continue to process already submitted tasks.
    service.shutdown();

    try {
        // wait at least 5 minutes for the tasks to complete
        if (!service.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) {
            // still not done yet -> force shutdown
            // this will interrupt currently running tasks.
            service.shutdownNow();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        // someone interrupted this thread. Shutdown tasks immediately
        service.shutdownNow();
        // propagate exception
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

So what happens here?

- First, all tasks are submitted.
- Then `shutdown()` is called on the `ExecutorService`. Note that the service will [continue to execute already submitted tasks, but it will not accept new tasks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--).
- Now, we wait for the service to terminate by calling [`awaitTermination`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) with a timeout of 5 minutes. If this method returns `true`, which means, that the service has terminated within time, everything is fine and we're done. But if it returns `false` after 5 minutes, it means that the service is still running because there are some tasks that need more time to complete.
- In that case, we shutdown the service immediately by calling `shutdownNow()`. Note that this method will not block! It just attempts to cancel all running tasks, usually by interrupting the threads that are currently executing them. *This is exactly why your tasks should response to thread interruption properly! If they don't do this, interrupting the thread will have no effect at all!*
- No matter if `shutdownNow` was successful - we are done and do not wait any longer. So there might still be some tasks that are running because they don't react upon thread interruption (usually because a task is either not implemented properly or it is uninterruptibly on purpose). But we simply don't care.
- Note the exception handler: When another thread interrupts the thread that is calling our method while it is waiting in method `awaitTermination`, an `InterruptedException` is thrown. We handle it by shutting down the service and re-throwing the exception! That is a good thing and makes our method a long-running-operation that is cancellable by itself!

Comment: it's a very clear explanation. I like the part that you mention there is no point of keeping track of the future. I'll try it and let you know

Comment: well I'll be damn surprised , it did the trick. I believe  **throw ex;** did the trick. even though the threads are not getting terminated. I get out of that method. then once everything else carried out all I needed to do was to add ***System.exit(0);*** to force exit the program.

Comment: @nafas As I mentioned, the method will terminate after at least 5 minutes no matter if the tasks are running or not. In your case it seems they are still running indeed - that's why the system will not halt without `System.exit(0)`! You should really check your task implementation and ensure, thread interruption is handled properly!

Comment: `throw ex` is not the important part here as it will only be called if _another_ thread interrupts the current thread. In your case, `awaitTermination` just returns `false` and the method exists after calling `shutdownNow` which seems to have no effect because your tasks ignore the cancellation!

Comment: I know **System.exit(0)** is a very bad practice. all I wanted to do was to get out of that part of the program(which thanks to your solution I do). once I'm out of that bit, I can talk to mother server. this is an extremely heavy computation which requires ~500 servers. so previously the efficiency was at 60% now the efficiency is at 95%

Answer (score 1):

Well... proper exception handling seems to be missing.

```
/**  
 * Waits if necessary for at most the given time for the computation  
 * to complete, and then retrieves its result, if available.  
 *  
 * @param timeout the maximum time to wait  
 * @param unit the time unit of the timeout argument  
 * @return the computed result  
 * @throws CancellationException if the computation was cancelled  
 * @throws ExecutionException if the computation threw an
 * exception  
 * @throws InterruptedException if the current thread was interrupted
 * while waiting  
 * @throws **TimeoutException if the wait timed out**  
 */  
V get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
    throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException;
```

If your call to `future.get(5l,TimeUnit.MINUTES);` expires, then an `Exception` is thrown and your `service` is never shut down.

So (one can assume) its internal threads are still running, at least the one that is executing your long running task). Seeing those are non-daemons thread (you'd have to custom the `ThreadFactory` of your executor for them to be), those pending threads prevent the JVM from shutting down.

If you wish to terminate the tasks forcibly, you can :

1. design your runnable task to respond to `Thread.isInterrupted()`, and exit when it sees that become true. (The practical effect of `shutdownNow` is to set the interrupted flag of your `executor`'s thread )
2. If you can't (because your are blocked in some library's method that does not listen to interruption), then having a dameon thread seems like the only option.

But anyway, I'd put the `executor`'s shutdown either earlier, or in a `finally` clause.

Comment: very interesting mate, I never considered this. But I'll try it and let you know.