# Thread name does not match when sending it to scheduleAtFixedRate

Tags: java, threadpool

I made a runnable class and created a thread but with a unique name but when I send this thread though `executor.scheduleAtFixedRate` it creates its own thread and I do not understand why is it?

I tried to read here but still, I do not understand this:
https://www.codejava.net/java-core/concurrency/java-concurrency-scheduling-tasks-to-execute-after-a-given-delay-or-periodically

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        ScheduledExecutorService executor =
                Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        Runnable runnable = new AutoUpdater();
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable, "MyThread");
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(thread, 0, 24, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    }
}

public class AutoUpdater implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.println(threadName + " is running...");
        System.out.println("Thread ended.\n");
    }
}
```

It should print the name MyThread but the output is:

```
pool-1-thread-1
```

and it should be maybe something like this :

```
pool-1-MyThread-1
```

Comment: The scheduler has its own threads it uses to execute tasks. Your thread object is just providing the code to be run, but not the name.

Comment: Can I change scheduler own threads name? and is it right to send a thead though executor?
Maybe it should be executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 24, TimeUnit.HOURS); ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` creates a pool which has it's own threads internally.

When you look at [`ScheduledExecutorService::scheduleAtFixedRate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) it takes [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) as first argument. And this `Runnable` will be run by some thread from the pool. Notice that [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) implements `Runnable` and you pass a `Thread` instance to `scheduleAtFixedRate` method so this thread's run method will be invoked by some other thread **but the thread that you passed wil not be started**. Generally to avoid any misconceptions you should pass simple `Runnable` here which will represent work that needs to be done.

If you want to change names of threads from this pool you would have to provide custom [`ThreadFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) which will be used by the pool to create new threads :

```
ThreadFactory threadFactory = runnable -> new Thread(runnable, "MyThreadName");

ScheduledExecutorService executor =
            Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(threadFactory);
```

**EDIT** :

For Java versions < 8 we could simply create new class implementing `ThreadFactory` interface :

```
class MyThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable runnable) {
        return new Thread(runnable, "MyThreadName");
    }
}
```

and then pass it :

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(new MyThreadFactory());
```

Comment: Could you explain how to create this ThreadFactory threadFactory = runnable -> new Thread(runnable, "MyThreadName");
?

Comment: What Java version are you using?

Comment: I am using java version 8

Comment: So the above code should work for you. What do you mean by "how to create" ?

Comment: It is ok I got it =D your edit helped me to get it right

Answer (score 0):

The executor service is creating it for you.
If you wish to override the naming of threads you can set options in the executor service.
See [Naming threads and thread-pools of ExecutorService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113746/naming-threads-and-thread-pools-of-executorservice)

Comment: is it right to send a thead though executor? Maybe it should be executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 24, TimeUnit.HOURS); ??